# Run a python script on all files in a directory

Tags: python, for-loop, absolute-path, pdftotext

First time posting a question here, hopefully, someone who experienced/tried this please share your insights... I've been working to get this far in the last few days and nights... now I am getting nowhere to loop this script on every file in a directory.

Bascially, these two scripts work perfectly fine it brings a pdf file and changes it to an excel workbook. Now what I need to do is going through all files from a selected directory and do the same job.

---

I am keep getting stuck at the opening the file stage - is this saying that the data (the pdf page - data[0]) cant be called in? or should i add more stages in to bring the dataset in...?

Do I have to create a list for the dataset so I can call in the data as you would have more than a data to call in.. is this why python can read the data[0] ???

[image]

**Revised Script**

```
# import 
import os
import glob
import pdftotext
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path
from string import ascii_uppercase

# open a pdf file
def to_excel(pdf_file):
    with open(pdf_file,'rb') as f: 
        data = pdftotext.PDF(f)
        
# operate data to get titles, values 
datas = data[0].split('\r\n')

finalData = list()
for item in datas:
    if item != '':
        finalData.append(item)

finalDataRefined = list()
for item in finalData:
    if item != '                          BCA Scheduled Maintenance Questions' and item != ' Do you suspect there is Asbestos at the property?' and item != '    Yes' and item != '    No' and item != '\x0c':
        finalDataRefined.append(item.strip())

titles = list()
values = list()

for num, item in enumerate(finalDataRefined):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        titles.append(item)
    else:
        values.append(item)

# get an output file name
       
OPRAST = values[1]
filename = work_dir / f"{OPRAST}.xlxs"

# create an excel workbook
excel_file = openpyxl.Workbook()
excel_sheet = excel_file.active

excel_sheet.append([])

alphaList = list(ascii_uppercase)
for alphabet in alphaList:
    excel_sheet.column_dimensions[alphabet].width = 20

excel_sheet.append(titles)
excel_sheet.append(values)

# save the excel workbook
excel_file.save(filename)
excel_file.close

# run a python script every file in a directory
alphaList = list(ascii_uppercase)

work_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Sunny Kim\Downloads\Do Forms")
for pdf_file in work_dir.glob("*.pdf"):
    to_excel(pdf_file)
```

Comment: Try wrapping your second script in a function and calling it for each element of abspath. It also helps to keep all import statements at the top of a file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I tried to warp the second script by using a function (def) and tried but still cant figure it out how to loop all files in a directory....

Comment: Are you sure you have `data = pdftotext.PDF(f)` **get executed**? Try `print(type(data))`, if get `WindowsPath` then `data = pdftotext.PDF(f)` doesn't get executed. As I mentioned before, now you `data` object is **not a pdf content object** but a **`WindowsPath`**object(indicated by the err reported), that means it's a path( path I mean a str like `C:\Users\Sunny Kim\Downloads\Do Forms\a.pdf`) rather than a file centent (like your pdf pages content `title, value, balabala`), only after you open this path and read the file can you get the pdf pages content and use `data[0]` to get 1st page.

Comment: Another thing, indent of you code is still not clear..., I guess you just paste them from jupyter notebook directly. In python, if you don't provide correct indent, it's really hard to understand your code logic except by guessing. For example, is statement `datas = data[0].split('\r\n')` in func `to_excel`? In your code, it is not, but it should be. Can you see the code I provide in my answer?

Comment: Hey Zhao, you were 100% right now it all works it was the indentation error  - I fixed that from the script below and now it's working perfectly!!! You are a legend! Thank you so so so much I don't even know what to say right now :-) I am so grateful

Comment: My pleasure! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I basically know what you want to do, but your code's indent is not so readable... especially it's python.

Your goal is to create a excel for each pdf file in you prefix dir? or aggregate all the pdf files together to a single excel file?

The follow coding is for the first goal.

Code logic.

1. get all the pdf file
2. loop over all the pdf file, for each:

   1. open pdf file
   2. some operation
   3. export to excel file

You full code maybe like this(just guess):

```py
# ----------------import part-------------------
import os
import glob
import pdftotext
import openpyxl
from string import ascii_uppercase
from pathlib import Path

def to_excel(pdf_file):
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as f: # this open the pdf file
        data = pdftotext.PDF(f)
    # ---------------operate the data, get title and value-----------
    datas = data[0].split('\r\n')

    finalData = list()
    for item in datas:
        if item != '':
            finalData.append(item)

    finalDataRefined = list()
    for item in finalData:
        if item != '                          BCA Scheduled Maintenance Questions' and item != ' Do you suspect there is Asbestos at the property?' and item != '    Yes' and item != '    No' and item != '\x0c':
            finalDataRefined.append(item.strip())

    titles = list()
    values = list()
    for num, item in enumerate(finalDataRefined):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            titles.append(item)
        else:
            values.append(item)

    # ------------------get output file name---------------------
    OPRAST = values[1]
    filename = work_dir / f"{OPRAST}.xlxs"
    # ------------------create excel file sheet------------------
    excel_file = openpyxl.Workbook()
    excel_sheet = excel_file.active

    excel_sheet.append([])

    alphaList = list(ascii_uppercase)
    for alphabet in alphaList:
        excel_sheet.column_dimensions[alphabet].width = 20

    excel_sheet.append(titles)
    excel_sheet.append(values)
    # --------------------save----------------
    excel_file.save(filename)
    excel_file.close
# -------------------main program---------------
alphaList = list(ascii_uppercase)
work_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Sunny Kim\Downloads\Do Forms")

for pdf_file in work_dir.glob("*.pdf"):
    to_excel(pdf_file)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Zhao - where i am at stuck is to open the pdf file to run the script.. i'vé attached the whole script to show you where i am at if you have time to look at...

Comment: and also I dont understand what does - export_xlsx_name do - does this should go to the last of the script to populate the excel workbook?

Comment: `export_xlsx_name` is just the `filename` in your code, the output name of excel file. And the error is because you treat a pdf file path as pdf file content ... I add full code in my revised answer.

Comment: Big shout out to you Zhao! I think you led me to this stage putting script all together - thanks a lot and yes my final goal is to bring all data into one excel workbook - however, for now I am populating it to a single excel workbook. so you understood me correctly... please see the revised script if you can - i am still getting stuck at the stage - calling the data to operate - hope the code looks right now...